# How to login with 2 user types

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
        try
        {
            if (!(ComboBoxut.Text == string.Empty))
            {
                if (!(ComboBoxut.Text == string.Empty))
                {
                    String str = "server=RAVI;database=sampledb;Integrated Security=SSPI";
                    String query = "select * from DentalLogin where usertype = '" + this.ComboBoxut.Text + "'and password = '" + this.TextBoxPwd.Text + "'";
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    SqlDataReader dbr;
                    con.Open();
                    dbr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dbr.Read())
                    {

                        string ut = dbr.GetString(0);
                        if (ut == "Doctor")
                        {

                            this.Visible = false;
                            DoctorHome Dochome = new DoctorHome();
                            Dochome.Show();

                        }
                        else if (ut == "Staff")
                        {

                            this.Visible = false;
                            StaffHome staffhome = new StaffHome();
                            staffhome.Show();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(" username and password incorrect", "login page");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Can you please tell me whats wrong with this code with a drop down button.
I have 2 user types in my form one is *doctor* another one is *staff*.

> If the user selected doctor i want to show a `doctorhome` Form.
>   If the user selected staff i want to show a `staffhome` Form.

I got error username and `pwd` incorrect.
But in db everything is correct `username` & `pwd`.
Please help me out this problem.

Comment: _Can u please tell me whats wrong with this code_ You tell us first. What is your problem exactly? Your question is not clear _at all_. And you get exception or error message? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use `using` statement to dispose your connections, commands and readers.

Comment: else  statement {  username and pwd incorrect }

Comment: Please add a row of your table to question, because I think your problem is in your comparing s.

Comment: already added table and rows in db with column name usertype and pwd with usertype doctor pwd mark

Comment: change your select, `select usertype from DentalLogin where ... ` mayby your usertype column isn't the first column.

Comment: I wanted just a sample data of a row of your table, I think changing `ut == "Doctor"` and other one to something like `ut.ToUpper().Trim() == "DOCTOR" will be the answer

Comment: And I forgot to ask about that; you have an error `exception` or just a showed `MessageBox` about incorrect `username` and `pwd`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This
 dbr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dbr.read())
{
  string value = dbr["Column Index"].toString();
if(value == "Doctor" ){
  this.Visible = false;
  DoctorHome Dochome = new DoctorHome();
  Dochome.Show();
}

}
```